# Download directory as individual files from OneDrive

Tags: download, onedrive

I am trying to download a directory from my OneDrive onto my local computer. The problem is OneDrive keeps compressing the files, and the zip file, especially when it's large, is corrupted. Is there a way to download a directory as an individual, uncompressed files?

Comment: Are you using the desktop client or the web client to do this?  If the web client requires you to compress the folder before you can download, and the browser you are using has a problem doing so.  You should use a different browser.

Comment: I've tried on multiple browsers, and downloading to different OSs. This seems to be an issue with OneDrive.

Comment: In order to migrate this to Web Applications SE you might want to indicate how large the folder is, how large the compressed file is, and the type of data contained in the folder itself.  I suggest just using the OneDrive desktop client, but that won't allow you to download just a single folder, the OneDrive web client is intentionally severely limited for a variety of reasons.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I ended up syncing OneDrive with an external hard drive that has more space.

Comment: So the issue was not OneDrive but local disk space?? VTC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best course of action is to download **[OneDrive for Windows](https://onedrive.live.com/about/en-US/download/)** and sync it with your OneDrive. This way the files get downloaded one-by-one to your hard drive without being compressed into zips. Also if you need to download a large amount of data on an unstable network you can avoid possible corruption of files being compressed and downloaded as zip.